# Oracle database 21c Express: blob store as product_image_lob_seg syntax incorrect, how to fix?

Tags: oracle, datagrip, oracle21c

I am using Oracle

```
Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0
```

I am reading book Murach's Oracle (old version of Oracle database) [https://www.amazon.com/Murachs-Oracle-SQL-Developers-2nd/dp/1890774804/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1890774804)

[image]

I practice

```sql
CREATE BIGFILE TABLESPACE bigtbs_01
  DATAFILE 'bigtbs_f1.dat'
  SIZE 20M AUTOEXTEND ON;

CREATE table product_images
(
    product_id    number primary key,
    product_image blob
) tablespace bigtbs_01 lob (product_image)
    store as product_image_lob_seg
(
    tablespace bigtbs_01
    chunk 32768
    disable storage in row
    cache reads logging
    pctversion 20
);
```

[image]

The error syntax at `store as product_image_lob_seg` , how to fix?

Comment: Please provide an error message you get. The above code works properly, see [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b4efc21bb78bf8d4d1041a189a48e0c9)

Comment: For advanced features of Oracle, you must use real database server.

Comment: Storage attributes are not an advanced feature and the above code (copied and executed as is) works as expected in my local docker image also (Oracle 21 XE). According to the below answers the error is not about Oracle at all, but IDE features (which may or may not be aligned with the database version). Internal database SQL parser is the only correct parser

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug on DataGrip side. I've filled a new ticket: [DBE-16303](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-16303).

Feel free to follow it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you didn't skip the creation of the segment `product_image_lob_seg`?

Comment: I don't know anything about *the creation of the segment `product_image_lob_se`*. Please guide me.

Comment: It's you reading the book not me... 
product_image_lob_seg is not a built-in ORACLE object, so for sure the book should explain how to create it in some chapter before the one creating the table.
But if the book is quite old, it's probably not speaking about CDB and PDB... so I guess you will have to adapt to your situation (running 21c...).

Comment: Segment is created when the object is created. LOBs are stored in separate segment, so you may provide a readable name for the segment to find it in `[dba|user|all]_lobs` when you declare lob column. There's no other operations of segment creation